# When did using global event handler attributes within html become "considered bad practice"?

Tags: javascript, html

Related: *[Why is using onClick() in HTML a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice)*. See also *[Unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)*.

> **Unobtrusive JavaScript** is a general approach to the use of JavaScript
>   in web pages. *Though the term is not formally defined* (emphasis added)

Questions:

1. At what point was the determination made that using `onclick` or
   other global event handler attributes within `html` was "considered"
   a "bad practice"?
2. By whom was the determination made that using global event handler attributes within `html` was a "bad practice"?
3. If the user who drafts the `html` and includes global event handler attributes within the `html` is aware of the event handler
   attributes' presence within the `html`, how could this be
   "considered" "bad practice"?
4. Should a composer of `html` not ever include an event handler attribute within `html`?
5. Are there any cases where including event handler attributes within `html` *would not* be "considered" a "bad practice"?
6. Exactly whose "consideration" of a practice should the composer of the `html`, `javascript` defer to? That is, what is the
   reference point for a composer to review whether a particular
   practice is currently "considered" "bad", "not bad" or "good"? Or,
   is there a list which tallies all "considerations" of those that
   "consider" the many possible practices which could be implemented
   within `html`, `javascript`?

For clarification, attempting to ascertain exactly when, and by whom, the term or phrase "bad practice" or "considered bad practice" was attached to the usage of global event handlers within `html`? And what is the official or pseudo-official document or set of documents which list the votes of those that participated in the "consideration" process that leads to a "bad" or "good" designation?

Or, is the term "considered bad practice" primarily opinion-based?

Comment: Global handlers within markup are considered a bad practice because *they're global*. Anything global is bad practice, especially in the JavaScript ecosystem. We used those before because *we didn't have any alternative at that time*.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Yes, "considered" by whom ? Was there a poll done ?

Comment: Everybody converged on their own minds I believe -- in other words, they're *really* a bad practice (*considered* is a weasel word). Simple example: if my script is loaded after yours (and sometimes even before yours), it has free reign over your global handlers.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi  _"Everybody converged on their own minds I believe"_ This is not very conclusive ? _"Simple example: if my script is loaded after yours (and sometimes even before yours), it has free reign over your global handlers."_ Not certain gather example description correctly; can you create a stacksnippets or jsfiddle to demonstrate ?

Comment: 1) Over time 2) by general consensus of the community given the changing nature of front-end design over the years.

Comment: Ah, delightful burden of proof :) Okay, you don't have to take my words as face value, [here's a fiddle to prove it](http://jsfiddle.net/7nur47gq/) (it relies on hoisting, I could have assigned a function expression instead, the result would be the same).

Comment: @Andy How is this substantiated ? Why is the phrase deferred to "considered" ? Instead of "I" ? Attempting to ascertain exactly when this determination was made ? And by whom ?

Comment: Why does it matter? If you don't agree with the consensus don't do it that way, but you'll be running against the grain of what has been mutually agreed upon _over the span of many years_ by tens of thousands of developers.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi The same could occur using `.addEventListerner` http://jsfiddle.net/7nur47gq/1/ ?

Comment: @Andy _"but you'll be running against the grain of what has been mutually agreed upon over the span of many years by tens of thousands of developers."_ Where is the document representing the mutual agreement ? Or, for that matter, the list of voters that did not or do not agree ?

Comment: @guest, ah, but that's because your handler *is still global*. When using `addEventListener()`, one would either use an anonymous lambda or protect the handler in a local scope.

Comment: There isn't one. There's years of people trying different ways of working (some documented). Some ways are better than others and people gravitate towards those methods of working. It can be best described as _an evolution_ of development practises. Evolution doesn't have a roadmap, some things work, others don't. Those that work, win.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Is `obj.original` global here http://jsfiddle.net/7nur47gq/2/ ?

Comment: @guest, of course it is (well, `obj` is and `original` is public). Are you seeing any scope around it?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Was attempting to illustrate that there does not appear to be a difference between the two where the handler is adjusted to return an unexpected result

Comment: @Andy _"There isn't one."_ Does this mean that either approach is primarily opnion-based ?

Comment: @guest, did you get what I was saying about lambdas and local scopes? I don't think we're making progress here.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi No, not really. From perspective here, do not realize any differences; though could be incorrect and missing something vital to "progress", however that could be defined

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Interesting that of the three current "close" votes, two cite "too broad" , one "primarily opinion-based". Is this the case ? Why would or could a user state "bad practice" where when seeking root of phrase one reaches "too broad" or "primarily opinion-based"  ?

Comment: @guest271314, no. The "good practice" version is what people believe serves their needs better _based on the technology with which they're working_.

Comment: @guest, I wouldn't know. I haven't voted to close either way. Yet.

Comment: @Andy _"is what people believe"_ Belief is very difficult to evaluate or place  credence in. Beliefs often change

Comment: Which is why this question is too broad for SO and why I voted to close it. You should take this to the JS chatroom and natter about it there to your heart's content.

Comment: @Andy Why "too broad" ? Does this reflect that usage of event handler attributes is primarily opnion-based ?

Comment: @Andy Chat room or meta probably would not get appropriate answer. Have a sense that the actual answer as to whether an approach is "bad", "good" or "not bad" is opinion-based

Comment: You're not going to get one here either.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Scope references were helpful in reference to this answer  http://stackoverflow.com/a/21638795/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, it is considered bad practice by "the community" -- the collective intelligence of average JavaScript developers.

Bad practice, by definition, is not something that's a rule that's decided by anybody, just like you can be bad at naming functions or have too long functions or using global variables all over the place, you can have your JavaScript event handlers assigned in HTML.

There was no poll and no W3C decision made. It's simply a result of many people's experience with them.

The main reasons, in my opinion are:

- The event handlers need to be global references, so everything
  that's bad about global variables in general applies to them.
- It's not very obvious where your global function is being used
  if you're only looking at the JavaScript code
- People generally prefer to keep their HTML clean of JavaScript and
  leaving their event handling completely in JavaScript land.
- Keeping the event handling assignment in JavaScript makes it so
  you don't have to change the markup to update your JavaScript code.
- If you have a lot of them around, it can get pretty repetitive. For example, when assigning the same event handler to every row in a table.
- You can't do all your event assignment in HTML, so you inevitably
  will have some in HTML and some in JavaScript land, which makes it
  feel extra messy.

However, there's a lot of dogma, and generally when there's a new way to do things the sheep herd will generally just run around in the same direction eschewing any other opinions. You'll hear a lot of people saying it's bad without them necessarily knowing why it's bad or knowing how to explain why they're bad.

So, being completely pragmatic about it, if you have a simple application and you just need to assign a single event handler, etc., it's your choice.

So IMO there's nothing *wrong* with it, and if you and the people you're working with like doing it that way, by all means, go ahead.

But yes, it's considered bad practice by the average JavaScript developer. With no authority.

Comment: _"The event handlers need to be global references"_ Is `obj.original` global http://jsfiddle.net/7nur47gq/2/ ?

Comment: *By the average javascript developer. With no authority.* Heh. Can you try a little experiment? For your next code review, try putting global handlers in your markup, and insist in leaving them there. I believe you'll get what *authority* means quite quickly ;)

Comment: I don't know if you're ready to hear this, but that's a globally accessibly reference. It may be name-spaced, but it's still globally accessibly.

These days javascript developers prefer to have their code not accessibly from the global scope at all. One of the reasons being that you will be able to minify the code way more efficiently.

Comment: _try putting global handlers in your markup. I believe you'll get what authority means quite quickly ;)_ -- fair enough :)