# Why does this string get changed to full element selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element that gets generated dynamically:

```
// gathers the name of the file the user is uploading
let fileName = escape(e.target.files[0].name).slice(0,9);

let icon = $(` // this extra space is for readability on SO
        <div class="fileImage" id="${fileName}">
           <div class="glyph-stack">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file file-icon"></i>
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file file-icon overlay"></i>
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove file-icon" onclick="removeFile(${fileName})"></i>
        </div>
        <span class="file-title">${fileName}</span>
        </div>`);
```

When I append the element to the DOM and inspect it, all instances of ${fileName} appear correctly. If a file named freeicons.zip is uploaded, "freeicons" appears everywhere I placed ${fileName}. However, once the removeFile function is called in the onclick handler:

```
 function removeFile(fileName){ 
    $('#'+fileName).remove();
 }
```

The variable fileName inside the function no longer equals "freeicons". When I inspect it, the variable is set to **div#freeicons.fileImage**, which is the selector for the entire element.

If, in the onclick handler call to removeFile() I wrap ${fileName} in single quotes:

```
`onclick="removeFile('${fileName}')"`
```

I get the string "freeicons" inside removeFile().

Why in the first case does it replace the string with the element selector? Is this something JQuery is doing when it creates this little element tree?

Comment: @bassxzero The function body is included at Question

Comment: what is `${fileName}` is this a new jquery thing??

Comment: You shouldn't be binding JS handlers inline. Instead, simply bind the click event to the remove icon instead (you might have to rely on event bubbling since the click icon isn't present at runtime). When the click event callback is fired, simply calling `$(event.target).closest('.fileImage').remove()` will suffice.

Comment: @Huangism That's string interpolation in template literals in ES6: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fileName` is a string, without quotes the parameter passed to the function at `onclick` is interpreted as a global identifier

```js
function removeFile(fn) {
  console.log(fn)
}

let fileName = "abc";

let el = `<div onclick="removeFile('${fileName}')">click</div>`;

$("body").append(el);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

```js
function removeFile(fn) {
  console.log(fn)
}

let fileName = "abc";
// `abc` is not defined at `catch`, where `id` is not set to `fileName`
let el = `<div onclick="try {removeFile(${fileName})} catch(err) {console.error(err)}">click</div>`;

$("body").append(el);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

> Why does this string get changed to full element selector?

`id` of element in `document` is global, attribute event handler is global. Without quotation marks surrounding the argument, the global `id` `freeicons` is referenced, resulting in the `DOM` element `#freeicon` being logged within the global event handler attribute event function

```js
function removeFile(fn) {
  console.log(fn)
}

let fileName = "abc";
// `abc` references the global `id` `"abc"`
let el = `<div id="${fileName}" onclick="try {removeFile(${fileName})} catch(err) {console.error(err)}">click</div>`;

$("body").append(el);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: just as a point of clarity, i didn't downvote, and I agree it was meaningless. do you have reference to docs for this behavior? I'd like to read up on it

Comment: @Cruiser [When did using global event handler attributes within html become “considered bad practice”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36388227/when-did-using-global-event-handler-attributes-within-html-become-considered-ba?), [id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id). Try `console.log(freeicons)`