# How to select two elements at once and make my code affect both of them with querySelector?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm adding my website a night mode. And I've done most of the coding part and while started to change some parts about design. I'm going to need to change my `hr`s in the HTML and add them a solid border to make them visible in the dark mode. Here's my code:

```
<p class="dark">
  <a id="moon" href="#" onclick="localStorage.setItem('mode', (localStorage.getItem('mode') || 'dark') === 'dark' ? 'light' : 'dark'); 
                localStorage.getItem('mode') === 'dark' ? 
                document.querySelector('body').classList.add('dark') : 
                document.querySelector('body').classList.remove('dark')" title="nm">Night Mode
                </a>
</p>
```

What I want to do is that add a `class` to my `hr`s as well with this code using `querySelector` but once I added the `hr`s to the code it only affects `body` and not the `hr`s. What can I do to make the code affect both of them.

The code bellow is working but I also found an eaiser way to do what I wanted. To CSS code I simply added this code and it is working nice as well.

```
body.dark hr {
border: 1px solid #808080;
}
```

Comment: change your styles .when body has class dark you can add required styles `hr`

Comment: And how do I do that? I have already created a CSS rule about hr, I just need to add the dark class to "hr"s.

Comment: then you should select hr not the body `document.querySelector('hr')`

Comment: The thing is that I can already select one. What I want is that select both of them, add the same class to both of them with the same code.

Comment: Could you use `querySelectorAll` and use a for loop to iterate through all the `hr`s?

Comment: What is the expected result of `localStorage.setItem('mode', (localStorage.getItem('mode') || 'dark') === 'dark' ? 'light' : 'dark'`?

Comment: To check what is the mode that is stored and make it dark mode if not stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.querySelectorAll()` and `.forEach()` method of `NodeList`

```
document.getElementById("moon").addEventListener("click", e => {
  localStorage.setItem('mode', (localStorage.getItem('mode') || 'dark') === 'dark' ? 'light' : 'dark'
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll("body, hr");
  elements.forEach(el => {
    if (localStorage.getItem('mode') === 'dark') {
      el.classList.add('dark') 
    } else {
      el.classList.remove('dark')
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Should I still be using this in HTML since I have been using other in HTML?

Comment: @BurakSümer Is there a need to use global attribute event handler? Whether to use global attribute event handler or not in HTML is a matter of opinion. That is your own decision. See [When did using global event handler attributes within html become “considered bad practice”? \[duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36388227/)

Comment: With this code I'm having an issue called " ',' expected. ts(1005)" on const. I have researched and updated TS. What might be causing the problem?

Comment: Found the problem, there was a ) missing before the const. This code seems like working for me. Thank you.